# Rails reaccept with workflow gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, workflow

am I able to reaccept already accepted object with the rails workflow gem?

My business case:

1. User wants to update a public profile data.
2. On every update admin has to review the changes made on the data
3. Admin accepts the changes and after that the data are visible to public
4. User changes the data once more time (update operation) and the new changes have to be reviewed again.
5. admin reviews again and accepts.

So what should be my [workflow](https://github.com/geekq/workflow)? As of now looks like this:

```
 include Workflow
  workflow do
    state :new do
      event :submit, :transitions_to => :awaiting_review
    end
    state :update do
      event :submit, :transitions_to => :awaiting_review
    end
    state :awaiting_review do
      event :review, :transitions_to => :being_reviewed
    end
    state :being_reviewed do
      event :accept, :transitions_to => :accepted
      event :reject, :transitions_to => :rejected
    end
    state :accepted
    state :rejected
  end
```

My problem is that once I change the state of my object to accepted, I am not able to go back to awaiting_review on second update. 
Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I used the workflow gem, I would just create another event to transition backwards.

```
state :accepted do
  event :submit, :transitions_to => :awaiting_review
end
```

I would keep the `submit` event name so it can be called when the profile is new, update or accepted state.

Comment: I receive "There is no event accept defined for the accepted state" when trying this, which means that it doesnt work. Do you have example? Could you post it on pastebin tnx.

Comment: I need to see your update actions to help further. Your code is calling accept! when its already accepted. Did you bypass the awaiting review state?

Comment: You can see my test here http://pastebin.com/YE4bfrdt. It is working, but the problem I am facing is that before accept the new changes are visible to public, which is wrong, the changes should be accepted first, then visible. I need to show the state with the last accepted data.